# Why doesn't my Reactive Form in Angular 4 update the value when set by datetimepicker

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular-reactive-forms, metronic

I'm trying to add a [datetimepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to my Angular 4 [Metronic](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/default/angular/components/forms/widgets/bootstrap-datetimepicker) website.
I've added it to my Reactive Form like so:

`<input formControlName="timeOfRemoval" data-provide="datetimepicker"  class="form-control m-input" id="timeOfRemoval" placeholder="Select date &amp; time" readonly="" type="text">`

Now this creates the picker just fine and it also sets the value in the field.
But what doesn't happen is that the `Reactive Form` is picking up the change in value.

When I want to submit the form the value for `timeOfRemoval` keeps being null.
When I remove the `readonly`, pick a datetime and update the value by adding and removing a space, it does work.

Of course this is not what I want, I want my `Reactive Form` to detect the change. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After you build up your reactive form in your component.ts file, if you do the following, is it registering the change of value?

```
this.myReactiveForm.get('timeOfRemoval').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log('new value is: ' + val);
    // if it is showing the value is changing, then maybe save
    // that value to a different variable in this component and use
    // it when the form is submitted
});
```

Comment: It actually doesn't :(. If I remove the readonly again and manualy 'edit' the field it does fire the console.log().
I was also looking for a work-around to temporarily store the value somewhere else but I also couldn't get that to work.
I tried to use ngModel but I couldn't get that to work. It looked to me that combining reactiveforms and ngModels does not work.
Also I tried to find something like (change)="change()" on the input. But I failed there too. Do you have any other suggestions?